# jQuery plugin setting height in error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, debugging

Strange issue, I've used [jQuery Coda Slider 2](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/) for many projects now but it's behaving strangely on this one.  I don't have any javascript errors being reported on the page and the script is loading because you can see the page load normally and then animate when the plugin kicks in.  For some reason, the javascript is dynamically adding `style="height: 0` to the `.coda-slider` element (a standard portion of the code generated by the plugin).

Due to the complexity of the code and plugin, it's probably best to just look at the live production version of the site here (watch for the video to load correctly and then disappear when the plugin sets their height to zero for some mysterious reason):

http://valeriaentertainment.com.s66112.gridserver.com/gallery/video-gallery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i've checked how coda-slider plugin works.  It seems to give the height according to the '.panel' height which you actually dont have.  Just add "class='panel'" to your

.
Something like:

```
<div class="coda-slider-wrapper"> 
                <ul class="coda-slider preload" id="home_slider"> 
                    <li class='panel'><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/12477617?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="620" height="411" frameborder="0"></iframe><br class="clear" /></li> 
                    <li class='panel'><iframe title="YouTube video player" width="620" height="379" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PnE14vUkEtc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br class="clear" /></li> 
                </ul> 
            </div>
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part. Cheers!